# Please explain to me why we have $scope.variable twice first inside and outside the nested function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
function MyController($scope){ 
$scope.clock = new Date(); <---here
var updateClock = function() {
$scope.clock = new Date(); }; <---and here
setInterval(function() { $scope.$apply(updateClock);}, 1000);
updateClock();
```

};
I thought I knew javascript but I cannot understand what author did it here. Please help me to understand this function! Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's updating the `$scope.clock` variable every 1000ms (by calling the `updateClock` function). It was initialized, and then updated. Something on the frontend is probably reading the `$scope.clock` variable as the "current time". I would suggest using Angular's `$timeout`, instead of `setInterval`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is initializing `$scope.clock` when the controller is created.  That's the only time the first `$scope.clock = new Date();` will be run.  The second time, the function is updating the `clock` property on the `$scope` object, to set it with a new date.

This block would cause $scope.clock to be undefined until the timeout executes 10 seconds later:

```
function MyController($scope){ 
    var updateClock = function() 
    {
        $scope.clock = new Date(); 
    };
    setTimeout(function() { $scope.$apply(updateClock);}, 10000);
}
```

This block, $scope.clock is initialized when the controller is created:

```
function MyController($scope){ 
    $scope.clock = new Date();
    var updateClock = function() 
    {
         $scope.clock = new Date(); 
    };
    setTimeout(function() { $scope.$apply(updateClock);}, 10000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a reply. But what happens if we had not initialized..the function still runs no?

Comment: Yes, the function would still run, but $scope.clock would be undefined until the first time the function is executed.  Since updateClock() is called at the end of the controller, the initialization isn't even necessary.

Comment: Yes that is exactly my point. the function that is inside the block will be executed anyways.. is there any other example you can show me that would clear up my understanding. Sorry to bother you.

Comment: Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: yes that was it. thank you so much!!!! I thought that was what you meant initially but..just had to make it sure.